# Swift doesn't set text in UITextField after the update to swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, swift3

I updated my `XCode` to `Swift 3` last week and it converted all my code to `Swift 3` version. After that I am trying to set a text inside a `UITextField` and it doesn't work. I have already redone the connections from the `UI` with the code but it doesn't work.

When I type inside the `UITextFiled` it appears, but when I try to set the text programmatically it doesn't.

```
@IBOutlet weak var codigoTextField: UITextField!

codigoTextField.text = "3654"
```

Comment: Tested on xcode 8.1 swift 3.0.1, . Everything is ok. Check your connection, or code again

Comment: I took a look inside the `storeboard` file and I noticed that XCode is note creating the connection with the `Outlet`. How ccan I fix that?

Comment: I would try deleting the text field from your storyboard and adding a new one with the correct connection.

Comment: Probably that will be the solution.

Comment: I have deleted all mu UI and redone it with new elements and new connections, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened, but I rebuilt all the UI and remade all the connections and it worked.